# Android: how to add custom soft keyboard when form field is selected in WebView

Tags: android, keyboard, uiwebview, webview, android-webview

I am using WebView to present UI. Is there any way that I can trigger custom soft keyboard when input text form field is selected?

Answer (score 1):

I just encounter a similar problem with the android WebView. When I select, in touch mode, a text input field, it does not pop-up the virtual keyboard whereas with the trackball it works fine.

I just found there: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e52109afda599301/b4cbc16e4e9e8e0d (last message from alien9) that calling

```
myWebview.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

solve the problem.

Comment: It is not what I asked. For example. If you have form in which you want to enter your phone and address, I would love to enable custom and different virtual keyboards for phone and address fields. With numbers only for phone for example.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want a customized keyboard UI? Android already supports keyboards for different input types. Start here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethod.html

Comment: It does, but this is webview. @Ralf provided good answer if not exactly one I hoped for. I still do not know how to invoke my custom keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at HTML5 - if you change your

```
<input type="text" ...
```

to for instance a

```
<input type="number" ...
```

you'll get a specialized soft keyboard for numbers.

Here is some more documentation: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html