# Android soft Keyboard not open in webView`

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I m Using WebView in AlertDialog to authenticate user to twitter.
but When i click on field in webview ,android keyboard doesnt open.
here is my code that shows how i added webview in alert dialog.
i implicitly call android keyboard but it open keyboard behind alert dialog.

here is my code.

```
public static void webViewDialog(final String authorizationURL, final int type)
{

    final boolean correctPin;
    System.out.println("In webViewDialog");
    container = new LinearLayout(context);
    container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    container.setMinimumWidth(200);
    container.setMinimumHeight(320); 

    webView = new WebView(context);
    webView.setMinimumWidth(200);
    webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webView.setMinimumHeight(380);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new TwitterWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(authorizationURL);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFbbd7e9);
    container.addView(webView);

    Builder webDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    webDialog.setView(container).setTitle("Twitter Login")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {

                    if (type == 0) 
                    {
                          twitterPinCodeDialog();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                }
        }).show();
    showVirtualKeyboard();

}
public static void showVirtualKeyboard()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {

         @Override
         public void run()
         {
              InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

              if(m != null)
              {
                // m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
              } 
         }

    }, 100);  
}
```

Comment: You need to explicitly set a View.OnTouchListener. See my previous question: [Tapping form field in WebView does not show soft keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200259/tapping-form-field-in-webview-does-not-show-soft-keyboard)

Comment: you r rught my friend..but i m opening webview in alert dialog..when i touch on webwiew android keyboard opend but behind alert dialog.not on the top of the View.

Comment: Yuppi...I have solved the problem.i had put one dummy edit text and set its visibility to gone.and add it after adding webview in linear layout..so everything going ok.when i touch on any field,android keyboard open.

Comment: @NiravBhandari I wonder, why does adding invisible view solve the problem?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is my solution to this problem:

Put a dummy edit text, and set it's visibility to `GONE`, and add it to a containing LinearLayout, after adding the WebView to the layout.

Example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(this);
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
EditText keyboardHack = new EditText(this);

keyboardHack.setVisibility(View.GONE);

webView.loadUrl(url);

wrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
wrapper.addView(webView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
wrapper.addView(keyboardHack, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);              

builder.setView(wrapper);

builder.create().show();
```

Once this is done, everything should work properly, and when you select an item in the WebView, the keyboard appears as expected.

Comment: I have added an example snippet to your post to make it easier to 'plug in' and use, but feel free to edit it out if you don't want it there.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I know I'm late to the party, but I just want to point out that YOU DA REAL MVP, Richard.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. But I wonder what's the science behind it?
@RichardJ.RossIII do you know why?

Answer (score 5):

I am using a PopupWindow with a WebView inside it and experienced the same problem, but if I set focusable to true in the parent the problem goes away:

```
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it in this way:

1. I override the **onCreateView()** method on the dialog fragment and define all view stuff configuration for my web view.

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);
       // do some config
       // some other stuffs

       loginpage.loadUrl(url);
       return view;
   }
   ```
2. On the **onCreateDialog()** method i just add these.

   ```
   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstaceState) {
       Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstaceState);
       dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       return dialog;
   }
   ```

In my case i wanted to show a dialog with no title. So due the DialogBuilder take care of creating dialog's view i decided to override the **onCreateView()** and just call the **super.onCreateDialog()** and add my window configuration.

Answer (score -1):

I also suffer from this problem, I solved this problem by customizing Dialog, here is my custom dialog code, hope so this is use full for you.

```
    TwitterDialog fb=new TwitterDialog(this);
    fb.abc();
    //fb.dismiss();



class TwitterDialog extends Dialog {
    Context context;
    String url="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2";
     public TwitterDialog(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context=context;
        }
 void abc(){
            LinearLayout mContent = new LinearLayout(context);
            mContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            float[] dimensions =new float[]{400.0f,500.0f};

            addContentView(mContent, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f),
                    (int) (dimensions[1] * scale + 0.5f)));

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams FILL =
                new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            WebView mWebView = new WebView(context);
            mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebClicent());
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
            mContent.addView(mWebView);

            TwitterDialog.this.show();
        }

         class WebClicent extends WebViewClient{

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("onLoadResource "+url);
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("onPageFinished "+url);
                                    //TwitterDialog.this.dismiss();
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                System.out.println("onPageStarted "+url);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

         }
  }//TWitterDialog
```

Comment: Would be useful to know what the solution is instead of just pasting in some source code. This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -5):

The reason your keyboard may not be showing up, is probably because you are using a device that already has a hard keyboard. ANY DEVICE WITH A PHYSICAL KEYBOARD does not need to show a soft keyboard... That is why it is not showing. Because your device or your emulator has a physical hard keyboard.