# Epub text box does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, epub, epub3

am having one task in epub (i.e) quiz .so the problem what iam phasing is,once the user read the question means he enter his answer in text box. so the problem is text box does not show the key pad for typing the answer.is any some other solution for this problem using java script?.is it possible

Comment: It sounds like your experiencing an issue with a particular device/ereader not displaying a virtual/soft keyboard upon your textbox being focused. Could you tell us what particular device/epub reader you are using?

Comment: Darryl_Lehmann  am using it on android tablet and also i implement it on Ipad

Comment: Very good, does the behavior happen consistently across both platforms. The reason I ask is there are numerous threads on Android development where the soft keyboard has trouble opening from within a dialog window. Any chance that's the case here? For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252832/android-soft-keyboard-not-open-in-webview

Answer (score 0):

you can add javascript or a javascript plugin like jquery but there are some changes you will have to make to your code. I added a flex slider with just a few changes. First take out the leading xml call in the html file then use a cdata wrap for your script. If you go to my youtube channel I did a couple of videos on it about a year ago. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geAnFKbW9wI
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use like below, am using this for interactive FL books.

```
<div contenteditable="true">_</div>
```

and also you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1391278/4202224) for contenteditable change events.