# Soft Keyboard not displaying on touch in WebView DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-webview, touch-event, android-dialogfragment

**Edit:** I have looked at the error [page for this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7189); no answers work. It seems it is an `Android` system bug that has not yet been solved.

First off I've referred to [this similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200259/tapping-form-field-in-webview-does-not-show-soft-keyboard) But the solution to that question does not seem to be the solution to mine. I have a `DialogFragment` that contains only a `WebView`. Everything in the `WebView` seems to be touchable. However, the problem is that when I touch a form field, the cursor appears but the soft keyboard never shows up!

Here's my code in the `onCreateDialog()` method within the `DialogFragment` class:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    WebView web = new WebView(getActivity());
    web.loadUrl(InternetDialog.this.url);
    web.setFocusable(true);
    web.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    web.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    web.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                        v.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    builder.setView(web);
    return builder.create();
```

How can I get the soft keyboard to show up when I select a form field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a system bug that has not yet been fixed. [More information can be found here.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7189) It seems as though this bug occurs differently for people and therefore has different solutions. For my particular case, there is only one solution (as I've tried everything else). Solution:

First, I created a layout for the `Dialog`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in the `DialogFragment` class in the `onCreateDialog` method:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.internet_dialog, null);

    WebView web = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.web);
    EditText edit = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    edit.setFocusable(true);
    edit.requestFocus();
    web.loadUrl(url);
    this.webView = web;
    builder.setView(v);

    return builder.create();
```

And that's all there was to it. The reason this worked was because I made an `EditText` which I gave the focus to yet made invisible. Since the `EditText` is invisible it doesn't interfere with the `WebView` and since it has focus it pulls the soft keyboard up appropriately. I hope this helps any stuck in a similar situation.

Comment: For me, I had to do both this hack and also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4977247/445348

Comment: This is still a bug, and still the workaround, on SDK 30 in 2021.

Comment: This is still a bug, and still the workaround, on SDK 31 in 2022.