# Softkeyboard coming, but can not type in page loaded in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

In my application, there is a web view to load some pages. In some pages, android key board is not poping up when touched on text fields. For example, in facebook page, it is not possible to type username and password. Has anyone got any idea regarding this?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200259/tapping-form-field-in-webview-does-not-show-soft-keyboard

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake in the question. The issue is that, I can not type on the text fields. Any way key board comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                    v.requestFocus();
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

It works for me, thanks [Tapping form field in WebView does not show soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200259/tapping-form-field-in-webview-does-not-show-soft-keyboard)