# Not Getting Virtual Key board Events in android using Web View

Tags: android, input, webview, keyboard

I have a login html page which is loaded in Webview as shon below

```
WebView loginScreen = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.loginWebView);

        final JavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
        loginScreen.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");

        loginScreen.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        //myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        loginScreen.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/login.html");

        loginScreen.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);


// and a key up event event after updating the username and password to get the key Events 

public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
            Toast.makeText(this, "coming insied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


but when i press go/enter button its not firing (Toast is not being displayed) the event, kindly let me know where am i going wrong
```

i have also tried using KeyDown & dispatchKey events which didnt work

```
Thanks in Advance,

Nagendra.
```

Comment: Please refer this link. 
may this help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4977247/2362301