# Changing the input source of form fields in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-edittext

Is there any way that I can change the input source of text fields of the webpages in webview? Instead of the popping up the android keyboard, i want to give the input of my own displayed keyboard to fields in Webview.

Comment: Did you manage it somehow??